# objectify, javascript and google endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying to figure out how integration between google endpoint, objectify and javscripts works. I made a real simple class named 'User'. All I am trying is to fetch a record from a Data Store and return this object back and use this in javascript.

However, the object does not seem to flow back properly. I do not see any details around this object using Chrome's developer tools... Any ideas? FYI, the record exists in the data store as I can see it while using the development console. I also can see the information as I've logged this info to the console as well. Thanks.

** JAVA CLASS **
    package com.Backend;

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.*;

@Entity
public class User {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    @Id String email;

public User(){
    super();
}

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

** GOOGLE ENDPOINT **

```
public class UserEndpoint {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UserEndpoint.class.getName());

static {
    ObjectifyService.register(User.class);
}

@ApiMethod(name = "getUser")
public User getUser() {
    User u = ofy().load().type(User.class).id("johndoe@domain.com").now();
    return u;
}
}
```

Comment: Finally found out what the issue is. It has to do with how the object was returned... It did not have any return value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what the issue is. It has to do with how the object was returned... It did not have any return value.